# Flutter set validator required or not required

Tags: flutter, dart

How set `TextFormField` required or not required?

Eg. If `required parameter` is true: `validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty ? 'Required!' : null,`. If `required parameter` is false: `Not required`.

Code:

```dart
Widget _textInput({controller, name, enable, autofocus, required}) {
  return Container(
    child: TextFormField(
      autofocus: autofocus,
      enabled: enable,
      cursorColor: Colors.black,
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black45),
      ),
      validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty ? 'Required!' : null,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to define you variable with type in constructor for example `required` should be like this `bool required`, then you can do this:

```
Widget _textInput({controller, name, enable, autofocus,bool required}) {
    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: autofocus,
        enabled: enable,
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black45),
          ),
        ),
        validator: required?  (value) => value!.isEmpty ? 'Required!' : null : null,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a enable bool anywhere in your class:

```
bool enable = true;


Widget _textInput({controller, name, enable, autofocus, required}) {
    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: autofocus,
        enabled: enable,
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black45),
          ),
        validator: (value) => enable? value!.isEmpty ? 'Required!' : null: null,   // you need to add another tertiary operator

      ),
    );
  }
```

Or you can also do:

```
validator: (value) { 
              if(enable){
                if(value!.isEmpty){
                  return 'Required!';
                }
                else{
                  return null;
                }
              }
              else{
                return null;
              }
              }
```

To ease things a bit